# JavaScript and Jquery If Statment Append

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Ok so I have a list and some of the text inside the list is to long so I want to use JavaScript and Jquery to trim the text and add ... to the end of the test if its longer than 30 characters.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Long List item Long List item Long List item </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Smaller List item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
</ul>
```

My Jquery at the moment:

```
$(function(){
    $("ul li a").html(function(){
        return $(this).html().substring(0,30);
    });
    $('.box ul li a').append(' ...');
});
```

This works but I want to add maybe an IF statment to only add the ... if the length of the text inside of the  tag is more than 30 characters. How would I go about doing that?

Thanks

Comment: If($("ul li a").html().length > 30){}...

Comment: @Blunderfest you should create a detailed answer so you can get credit.

Comment: Are you a ware to the CSS option that might be much simpler in your case? For example:https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test the length in the function that's creating the substring, and add the ellipsis there.

```js
$(function(){
    $("ul li a").html(function(i, html){
        return html.length > 30 ? html.substr(0, 30) + " &hellip;" : html;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Long List item Long List item Long List item </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Smaller List item</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

BTW, the current HTML of the element is passed as an argument to the callback function, so you don't need to use `$(this).html()` inside it.